# How to use CTelephony API with Qt Symbian

Tags: qt, symbian

I want to use CTelephony API in Qt Symbian project but after including `etel3rdparty.h` and `etel3rdparty.lib` as library and header in `.pro` file like this:

```
LIBS += C:/NokiaQtSDK/Symbian/SDK/epoc32/release/armv5/lib/etel3rdparty.lib
INCLUDEPATH += C:/NokiaQtSDK/Symbian/SDK/epoc32/include
```

I am getting a lot of compilation errors.

Please share if someone faced and find the solution of this problem.

Comment: Without knowing the errors, how would we be able to help you?

Answer (score 2):

You are not supposed to include each library with the complete path in the .pro file. You need only the name of the lib, without the extension, prefixed with -l, i.e. in your case

```
LIBS += -letel3rdparty
```

Also, you would normally not need to add epoc32\include to the include path, as it's added by default.